# How do I store user/pass info in .my.cnf for mysqlsh?

Tags: mysql

`mysqlsh   Ver 8.0.12 for Linux`

I can create a .my.cnf file with credentials for mysql client and mysqldump but I can't find a way to make it work for mysqlsh commands.

Is there a way?

I want to check my cluster status from the command line without having to enter the password each time.

Comment: Try this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-pluggable-password-store.html

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqlsh` itself remembers the password after one use.

You will be prompted for a password, and after authentication `mysqlsh will prompt you to remember it

```
Save password for 'user@localhost:3306'? [Y]es/[N]o/Ne[v]er (default No): y
```

Then you can connect via mysqlsh without using a password:

```
mysqlsh --mysql -u user -h localhost -P 3306 -e "SELECT 'Hello World';"
```